# Capybara undefined method 'create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In a view I have a `link_to`helper that posts to the Commitments controller:

```
    <%= link_to "Engage in this project",
    commitments_path( {participant_id: current_user.id, participated_project_id: p.id}),
    method: :create %>
```

When I try to run the following integration-test:

```
 describe "participating in a project" do
   let!(:project) {FactoryGirl.create(:project)}
   before do
     visit projects_path
     click_on "Engage in this project"
   end
   it "should add that project to the users participated projects" do
    user.participated_projects.should include(project)
   end
  end
```

… I get the error

```
 NoMethodError:
 undefined method `create' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Browser:0x007ffcc1072ce8>
```

The code works in a manual test, however I would like to use Capybara, any ideas=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:create` is not a HTTP method. If your link is a post link, then the method is `:post`.